# Set initial value of a state using react hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am displaying a dropdown menu with the list of Ids that I fetch from an api. When I change the selected value, I would like to update a state with a newly selected ID. The display and selection works fine but in order to display initial value before the selection is made what should be the passed as the initial value of the state.

```
const [selectionValue, setSelectionValue] = useState();

const handleSelectionChange = (value) => {
  setSelectionValue(value);
}

       <Select 
          isOpen={isSelectOpen}
          onOpenChange={setIsSelectOpen}
          value={selectionValue}
          onValueChange={handleSelectionChange}>
            {apidata.map(optionItem => <SelectOption key={optionItem.rID}
                                                    value={optionItem.rID}>{optionItem.rID}</SelectOption>)}
       </Select>
```

Currently, on page load the dropdown menu is empty as initial value is not set

[image]

I am trying to understand what should be the initial value of the state. I cannot set it as apiData[0].rdID as state is defined before api fetch is finished. Then what should be the value ?

Comment: How do you use `apidata.map` before it's loaded then?

Comment: Should just be blank (`""` or `null`) and then provide a blank value for your select component.

Comment: I don't understand by what you mean by provide blank value for your select component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options here. If you can use a placeholder value while your data is being fetched from your API, you can just use the following

```
const [selectionValue, setSelectionValue] = useState("Placeholder Text 
Here");
```

If you need that data, you'll need to render the component after your data is fetched. That can look as simple as something like

```
const SelectComponent = (apiData) => {
    // Now you have access to the data on render, so you can declare state with an initial value here
    const [selectionValue, setSelectionValue] = useState(apiData[0].value);
    const handleSelectionChange = (value) => {
        setSelectionValue(value);
    };
    <select
        isOpen={isSelectOpen}
        onOpenChange={setIsSelectOpen}
        value={selectionValue}
        onValueChange={handleSelectionChange}
    >
        {apiData.map((optionItem) => (
            <SelectOption key={optionItem.rID} value={optionItem.rID}>
                {optionItem.rID}
            </SelectOption>
        ))}
    </select>;
};

const App = () => {

    // Assuming you're fetching data here and setting it to `apiData`

    if (!apiData) {
        // Render whatever loading screen/component here
        return <p>Loading..</p>;
    } else {
        return <SelectComponent apiData={apiData} />;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I added placeholder text for now.